# Cyclic Groups, inverses, rings and subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I am trying to better understand the cyclic groups and so far understand that a non-trivial subgroup is a subgroup that **DOES NOT** contain just the element identity alone, i.e. $\langle 6\rangle = \{6\}$ is a **TRIVIAL** subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.

However, how would one go about finding the **NON-TRIVIAL** subgroups? Lets say for example cyclic group $G = (\mathbb{Z}/89\mathbb{Z})^\times$. The factors of $89-1=88$, are $\{1,2,4,8,11,22,44,88\}$ so these are the orders of the elements.

Now I think I found a few **NON TRIVIAL** subgroups, but I am not sure if they are correct
$$
\langle 3\rangle = \{3,9,12,15,18,\ldots\}\\
\langle 4\rangle = \{4,8,12,16,\ldots\}\\
\langle 15\rangle = \{15,30,45,\ldots\} 
$$

Comment: There's **NO NEED** to **SHOUT** :P

Comment: Any subgroup of any cyclic group is cyclic. Just pick powers of the generator that share a factor with the order of the original group.

Comment: The question is really unclear. What do you mean by $\langle 6\rangle=\{6\}$? What is $6$ here? An element of which group?

Comment: @Shaun what would be some examples please Sir

Comment: See my answer below. It delineates the non-trivial subgroups of cyclic groups.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subgroups you found are indeed non-trivial. In general the cyclic subgroup $\langle g\rangle$ generated by any non-identity element $g$ of a group $G$ must be non-trivial, since it contains at least $g$. (To enumerate all the elements of a cyclic subgroup of a finite group, just keep taking powers of the generator $g$ until you have the identity in your subgroup, then stop.)

For example, in your group $(\mathbb{Z}/89\mathbb{Z})^\times$, you can take $g=55$ and calculate its powers. We find $g^1 = 55$, $g^2 = 3025$, which $\equiv 88 \pmod{89}$. Then $g^3 = 166375 \equiv 34 \pmod{89}$, and finally $g^4 = 9150625 \equiv 1\pmod{89}$ is the identity. So $\langle 55\rangle = \{55, 88,34,1\}$ is a non-trivial cyclic subgroup of order 4. (Of course, we could have avoided the huge powers by performing multiplication on the "modded" terms.)

Comment: Could you be kind enough to give some examples please?

Comment: You can take any group you like to be an example! Then choose an element $g$ that is not the identity, then keep taking powers of it $g, g^2, g^3, \ldots$ until you hit $g^n=e$ where $n$ is the order of $g$ and $e$ is the identity. Then $\{g, g^2, \ldots,e\}$ is a cyclic subgroup that is not trivial.

Comment: Sir thank you Sir, I don't suppose you could be so kind enough to do me some examples please? God Bless

Comment: Okay, take $G = S_3$, the permutation group on 3 letters, and $g = (123)$. This generates the subgroup $\{(123), (123)^2, (123)^3\} = \{(123), (132), e\}$.

Comment: Sorry sir, now i am super confused. i am so stupid i am sorry i am failure in life. i dont suppose you can edit answer to show example for my Z*89 please sir

Comment: Sure, give me a second.

Comment: Your method doesn't work for $\Bbb Z\cong\langle z\mid \rangle$, @marcelgoh.

Comment: @Shaun, you're right, it only works in finite groups. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Tip: Instead of doing, say, $g^5$, do, for example, $g^5=g^2g^3\cong 88\times 34\pmod{89}$; better yet: recognise that $88\cong -1\pmod{89}$ then proceed from there.

Comment: @marcelgoh Sir, I think I get it now!!! OMG!! Sir, just quick one, how did you derive or determine 55 may be a subgroup, as in what made you try 55? Are there ways of determining more than 1 subgroup, i.e. other numbers that are not 55?

Comment: ANY starting number gives a subgroup, i.e. you will always eventually hit the identity! I just chose 55 because I calculated that it would be a small subgroup.

Comment: @marcelgoh Sir, thank you so much for your answer Sir!! God Bless You!!!! I am so happy right now and I think I finally get it. I will accept you answer but can you please kindly clarify this for me? So <55> = {55,88,34,1} is a subgroup of Z*89 with order 4 right?

Answer (score 0):

A [presentation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupPresentation.html) of a (finite) cyclic group $\Bbb Z_n$ for $n\in \Bbb N$ is

$$\langle a\mid a^n\rangle.$$

Suppose $n=mk$ for some non-trivial $m, k\in\Bbb N$. Let $b=a^m$. Then $$\langle b\mid b^k\rangle$$

defines a group isomorphic to a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_n$ of order $k$.

---

For an infinite cyclic group, say, $(\Bbb Z, +)$, then the subgroup given by $(\nu \Bbb Z, +)$ for some $\nu\in\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}$ is non-trivial. (Why?) Here $\nu\Bbb Z=\{\nu z\mid z\in\Bbb Z\}$.

Comment: Thank you Sir, I don't suppose you can do a few examples for my case please? I am self taught student and willing to learn new things everyday. would really mean a lot if you could kindly help me

Comment: Sure: $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ is isomorphic to the subgroup $\langle [2]_6\rangle=(\{[0]_6, [2]_6, [4]_6\}, +_6)$ of $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$, generated by $[2]_6$, because $\gcd(6, 2)\neq 1$.

Comment: Does that help, @TomazWiszvortiox?